# How to print an array coming from Ajax request

Tags: php, html, ajax, laravel

This is my controller:

```
public function updateCustomerRecord(Request $request)
    {
        $datda = $request->all(); // This will get all the equest data.
        $teste = "teste";
        $selectt = DB::select('select * from users');
        return response()->json(['success' => true, 'teste' => $teste, 'selectt' => $selectt]);
    }
```

This is my ajax on the view:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#getRequest').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
    method: 'POST', // Type of response and matches what we said in the route
    url: '/customer/ajaxupdate', // This is the url we gave in the route
    data: {'id' : id}, // a JSON object to send back
    success: function(response){ // What to do if we succeed
        var theDiv = document.getElementById("teste");theDiv.innerHTML = response.selectt[1].;
        console.log(response); 
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { // What to do if we fail
        console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
        console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
    }
    });
    })
})
```

By the console.log I am getting the following data:

[image]

I am expecting to do a foreach and echo the entire array.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Sorry I'm not following. You want to print the entirety of the array separately, sub-elements included? Print the contents of selectt?

Comment: Yes, I want to print the array separately with the sub-elements included. @Kurisu

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct, you want to access the contents of selectt and print them separately, right?

That's easily done with a foreach loop.

```
for (const customer of response) {
    console.log(customer);
    // Do stuff with 'customer' if necessary
}
```

If that's not it, feel free to let me know and I'll update the answer accordingly.